# creating anymous type. type mytpe = typeof(nothing);?

Tags: c#, typebuilder, assemblybuilder

i read here how to [create anonymous types at runtime in c#](http://benohead.com/create-anonymous-types-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/)

```
AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly =
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("MyDynamicAssembly"),
  AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

string propertyName = "prp_1";
//Type propertyType = new Type();

ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyDynamicAssemblyModule");
TypeBuilder dynamicType = dynamicModule.DefineType("MyDynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);
PropertyBuilder property =
dynamicType.DefineProperty(
                    propertyName, 
                    System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.None, 
                    propertyType,             // idk what to put here?
                    new[] { propertyType }    // and here ?
                );

//call this first
AddProperty(dynamicType, propertyName, propertyType );

//then we ' ll dynamic type
Type myType = dynamicType.CreateType();
```

function that is called

```
public static void AddProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
```

there is propertyType in the code i dont know what to put there.
can i make

```
 type mytype = \\typefree?
```

thank you.

Comment: One useful link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After a `@` comes C# and C# is case-sensitive. Try  /HTML/Html/

Comment: henk that really worked.  i also got  big HTML text from other so what a mindfck than you... so much

Comment: @blackholeearth0_gmail: please don't try to edit other people's post if you think it's not relevant. You can leave comments if you wish to inform the author.

Comment: @blackholeearth0_gmail: if you have another question, please post it as another question.

Comment: @stefan if  so hadnt banned me i would have asked different question.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This Answer was correct for the question but question has since been changed.

I think you are looking for an object type so if the property was a string then you would be using

```
typeof(string)
```

in place of propertyType. Ah sorry missing the anonymous bit. You could try using dynamic

```
typeof(dynamic)
```

which would have the same effect as

```
typeof(object)
```

but dynamic is not typesafe so any properties that don't exist won't be picked up until runtime and both are a bit like saying 'put anything here'. The safest and best thing to do would be to create a class for the anonymous type.

Comment: the 3rd option should work then. but there is no way to define the type of something anonymous as it is anonymous.